# How to Map Discriminator Column when base type is IdentittyUser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I customized `IdentityUser` and named it `User`. Now extending `User` as `Doctor` and `Secretary`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
//...

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string UserType {get; set;}
    //some props
}

public class Doctor : User
{
    //some props
}

public class Secretary : User
{
    //some props
}

//...
```

I know that EF Core will create a Discriminator as shadow property but I want to map this Discriminator to User.UserType property. So here is my configuration on DbContext:

```
builder.Entity<User>()
            .HasDiscriminator(u=>u.UserType)
            .HasValue<User>("user")
            .HasValue<Doctor>("doctor")
            .HasValue<Secretary>("secretary");
```

I got this error when adding migration:

```
The CLR property 'UserType' cannot be added to entity type 'IdentityUser' because it is declared on the CLR type 'User'.
```

Why does this error happen? Is this the nice way I go?

Do you know any proper way of making different types of users?

Comment: **entity type** 'IdentityUser' inside the error message is indication of something wrong, because `IdentityUser` must not be an entity. Make sure you pass your customized `User` class as `TUser` generic parameter to the base identity related classes, including the db context, e.g. `YourDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>`

Comment: @IvanStoev You were right. Here was my context `MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext`, I changed it to `MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>` and the problem resolved.

Comment: @IvanStoev Leave your comment as a response so I would approve it as a proper response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed

```
MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext {...}
```

to

```
MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {...}
```

And the problem resolved.